# How to skip empty rows with offset in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Good afternoon.

I want to combine lines with a shift, and I don't know how to do it.
My data is repeating every 3 rows.
I tried using QUERY but it didn't work for me.

Table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yi8HUqBJseOOpME1LqotYoZHtUXAkqZO47bmUh9ts2k/edit#gid=0

Any help is welcome.

[Initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viRQd.png)

[What I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4nxN.png)

So far I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(z,scan(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),
     map(unique(z),lambda(Σ,{Σ,bycol(B2:G,lambda(Λ,ifna(+filter(Λ,z=Σ,Λ<>""))))})))
```

[image]